# svn - ... is not under version control

Tags: eclipse, svn

Estou tentando fazero `CleanUp` ou `Commit` do meu projeto no eclipse e está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> svn: Error modifying entry for 'teste'
>
> svn: 'teste' is not under version control

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Muito provavelmente porque você não criou um repositório em `teste`. Fora isto só consigo imaginar, pelo menos só com estas informações, que algo pode estar corrompido. Tem um diretório `.svn` lá?

Comment: Então... eu fiz uma cópia de uma pasta pelo eclipse e renomeei... Foi ao que começou o problema, e para tentar resolver exclui a pasta no eclipse e o problema continua.  Todas as pastas do projeto tem a pasta `.svn`

Comment: Tenta rodar `svn status` e depois `svn cleanup`

Comment: Quando você cria um repositório, toda manipulação nele deve ser feita pelo SVN. Se você renomeia sem usá-lo, você cria um problema. Ele já não sabe mais o que fazer com aquilo.

Comment: não encontrei o `svn status` no eclipse que é o que estou usando. O `cleanup` retorna o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pois é, agora aprendi que não posso copiar as pastas. Mas como faço para tentar corrigir o meu erro?

Comment: Por linha de comando, terminal, @Mamga